# Apache Zeppelin process not starting

Tags: apache-spark, apache-zeppelin

I'm new to apache spark and apache zeppelin. I am trying to set up Zeppelin with spark on a mac with M1 chip. I have spark and java installed at
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec` and
`/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.1` locations respectively.

## My .zprofile is as follows

```
export JAVA_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/openjdk/19.0.1 <br/>
export SPARK_HOME=/opt/homebrew/Cellar/apache-spark/3.3.1/libexec <br/>
export ZEPPELIN_HOME=~/Desktop/zeppelin-0.10.1 <br/>
export PATH=$JAVA_HOME/bin:$SPARK_HOME/bin:$ZEPPELIN_HOME/bin:$PATH <br/>
export PATH="$PATH:/Users/kanner/Library/Application Support/JetBrains/Toolbox/scripts"
```

I have added `JAVA_HOME` and `SPARK_HOME` to zeppelin config file.

## What I get in the terminal when I start zeppelin

[image]

## Error message I find in logs after starting zeppelin

```
ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH: :/Users/kanner/Desktop/zeppelin-0.10.1/*::/Users/kanner/Desktop/zeppelin-0.10.1/conf
Error: Could not find or load main class org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer
```

What am I doing wrong?

I have tried various solutions to similar question on here including

```
sudo bin/zeppelin-daemon.sh start
```

Answer (score 0):

This means that the `org.apache.zeppelin.server.ZeppelinServer` class is not present anywhere on your classpath. This class comes from the `zeppelin-server-0.10.1.jar` file, which I expect should be on your computer somewhere because it seems like you've installed it.

Try to find where that file lives. If you can't find it, you can download it from [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.apache.zeppelin/zeppelin-server/0.10.1) but I would suggest reinstalling Zeppelin from scratch if you can't find it because other things might have gone wrong.

Once you know where that file lives, you must make sure that the directory it lives in is also in that `ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH` variable you showed us. Right now its value is:

`ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH: :/Users/kanner/Desktop/zeppelin-0.10.1/*::/Users/kanner/Desktop/zeppelin-0.10.1/conf`

I expect the solution will be something simple like correcting the value of one of your environment variables, to make sure that the directory with that jar inside of it also shows up in the `ZEPPELIN_CLASSPATH` variable.

Hope this helps!

Comment: Thank you for your help. The issue went away when I downloaded the Zeppelin binary with all interpreters. I had initially downloaded the source.

Comment: Ahhh right, good catch!